# Can we have "2021: a year of EoQS"?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates, statistics, low-quality-posts, moderation

In Paramanand's [questionnaire](https://math.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1) response, he suggests that the effects of the [EoQS](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards) should be studied. This made me realise that I don't really know anything past the "theory" of the EoQS since its announcement (28th April 2021), and I guess this is because  I haven't been actively trying to enforce it (I spend my 'moderation time' more on editing and reviews), I don't frequent [CURED](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2165/cured), and I have not (yet?) been banned by it. Really, my main exposure to it is via others' meta posts.  I only sometimes notice EoQS offenders "in the wild". I also suspect certain high-rep users no longer post, or even have an account.

There are the posts [2020: a year in moderation](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33035/2020-a-year-in-moderation) that give summary statistics on moderator actions (community moderation and otherwise) Is it possible to similarly get a rough idea on what and how much has happened since the EoQS began to be enforced?

Some ideas off-the-cuff:

- number of comments (on main) referencing the EoQS
- number of answers/questions deleted/closed due to enforcing the EoQS.
- number of suspensions due to enforcing the EoQS (possibly split into low/high rep, and duration of suspension)
- number of users requesting to close their account citing disagreement with the EoQS
- Do high rep users post answers less frequently?
- Is there some sort of metric to see how much time the EoQS is taking out of moderators?  (This would also be nice for the upcoming new mods to know what they're getting into.)
- Are users that receive multiple EoQS comments downvoted more?

And of course, the effect of the EoQS. Any way to quantify the following questions?

- Do we have significantly less low quality Q&A pairs in the system than we would have without the EoQS?
- Do we have significantly more good Q&As in the system than we would have without the EoQS? (i.e. did the low quality questions get improved into good ones)
- Has the situation with duplicates improved?

Of course, the easier to obtain the data, the better; the mods are busy enough as is (hence the election). But I suspect many of these are not so easy with merely SEDE because low quality answers (with said comments) are more likely to be deleted (and hence deleted off SEDE IIRC).

One rough measure I suppose would be the difference between the 2020 and 2021 "a year in moderation" numbers, when 2021's comes out, but there are many confounding variables.

Comment: I doubt if the data related to suspensions can be made public.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh well, the number of suspensions per year is [made public](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33035/2020-a-year-in-moderation). If the data is already collected (ok, big if), I don't personally see it as a big jump. Perhaps I am hoping for too much when I ask for further splitting into smaller categories e.g. duration, rep bands etc

Comment: Yeah split into categories might not be allowed. But I think things which can be made public may be shared. In fact a simple measure of effectiveness would be to check the number of EoQS flags in last month compared to those at the beginning of EoQS implementation.

Comment: I've counted at least 6 suspensions of high-rep users (who shall remain nameless) for "low quality contributions", all of whom have only ever output quality work, and endeavoured to help the users here as much as possible. Further, I've encountered one such user confess to being afraid to answer a question, one that I believe was adequate if not outstanding, for fear of being suspended again. Perhaps some will see this as a victory, but as I said in the EoQS announcement, this is a dark period in MSE's history.

Comment: No. of comments might be hard to count. No. of posts closed/deleted is not really related to EoQS.

Comment: One recent trend I've seen and practiced lately is that comments now contain hints and partial answers. In the past (early days?), one was encouraged to post such comments as answers instead. I'm not sure which is better, either way. At least, (hopefully) you won't be suspended for giving hints and partial answers in comments...

Comment: @lhf I don't think "early days" is to the point. The "don't post answers in comments" is rather a global SE thing, which was faced with some skepticism.

Comment: A problem with this request is that a lot is subjective; see @TheoBendit comment. Moreover as regards, closure deletion and improvement, there is no direct link as EoQS is concerned. What did change is that the creators of the deleted content are now held responsible. For years they could just keep posting and posting while others kept deleting and deleting. That's specifically regarding the second point.

Comment: @quid and Arctic Yes, I can agree that I didn't think those numbers through, they aren't very well linked. Because of the subjective element I tried to look for lots of angles to look at...suggestions that would be easy on the mod team welcome!

Comment: @TheoBendit: I can fully understand the sentiments behind your comments. I have deep respect for some of the people who were suspended due to EoQS primarily because of their mathematical knowledge and polite interactions with me. And believe me this is not about victory or losing some battle.

Comment: Just because suspensions may have increased, could mean "in so many previous years, the number of suspensions reflected a problematic view of only suspending askers for low  quality content, and rarely, their answerers.  So we may be seeing how problematic that oversight was all those years.

Comment: What you might have counted, High Rep or not, might merely indicate how so many "High Rep" users continue to accumulate rep, by answering "do my work for me" questions.  I'd argue, if that's how they continued to work, it was a well deserved action taken by mods.  They would not have gotten suspended, if they took comments from users seriously, read the oft-linked EoQS, and take it seriously.  Suspension occurred only after a moderator warning, on top of all the "heads up".  It's been a long-standing myth on this site that "very high rep" correlates with "users to respect."

Comment: Actually, @CalvinKhor. I'm game for that, if we name other years as "The Dark Ages", and 2021 as the Enlightenment: *The* year of EoQS, the enforcement of standards that are in no way new; only their enforcement is new.

Comment: Also, as any researcher will acknowledge, asking your questions only six months after introduction is far too premature, given six months is only 1/20 th time length of time many bad habits evolved.

Comment: While I was ok with evaluation a month ago (I even commented on the EoQS page to this effect), I'm not going to change tack. I would like to see what the impact has been, but will continue because in my experience, I can envision a site where people are more at ease with following and ensuring that the guidelines are followed by all than is currently the case, which is paramount for me. As long as any revealed statistics don't lead to a panicky emotional response from the community, I'm fine, but I can't be that confident, given I've already seen "the year" and "dark day" being used here.

Comment: Assuming that something like a *three strikes rule* has been in use, I'm a bit surprised by the relatively high number of EoQS related suspensions. To get such a suspension one needs to ignore two stern warnings from the mods. That. Requires either gall or stubborness (combined with having ignored meta for a number of years). Then again, EoQS definitely brought a change of the site culture. So perhaps inertia is the more likely explanation.

Comment: Personally, what I really want to see is the thing that would likely be hardest to measure: the effects of our policies on PSQs. EoQS is, ultimately, a tool in service of the long term goal to combat the ever increasing flood of PSQ spam, and improving question quality in general. What we want is a costs benefits analysis to see if it's helping us achieve this goal efficiently, but it's difficult to do a costs benefits analysis without a good way to measure the benefits, and without that, all we can hope to see is downside.

Comment: "...the ever increasing flood of PSQ spam..." @Alex, citation?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I can believe #PSQs have increased with more online-only classes and the growth of Math.SE (But I'm not saying no to more stats)

Comment: @amWhy "Just because suspensions may have increased, could mean "in so many previous years, the number of suspensions reflected a problematic view of only suspending askers [...]" Right, but I hope We are learning! Are high-reps still often infringing, or are we more or less following the EoQS? I quite like Paramanand's suggestion of just sampling a couple of months' EoQS flags; hoping to see this drop sharply.

Comment: @amWhy "What you might have [...] if that's how they continued [...]  if they took comments from users seriously, [...]  It's been a long-standing myth on this site that "very high rep" correlates with "users to respect." I think you might be missing the point of statistics. I don't want to have to pepper my thoughts and sentences with "might" and "if" like this. And I can at least assure you, *I* do not respect many users with high rep.

Comment: @amWhy "Also, as any researcher will acknowledge, asking your questions only six months after introduction is far too premature, given six months is only 1/20 th time length of time many bad habits evolved." Sorry, I think this is completely unfounded. `"mid year evaluation"` gives so many results on google.  And many interventional studies (published) are conducted on the scale of *weeks* (e.g. training camp studies), so there's no backing from "research". What I will give you though is perhaps we should have it named "2021: a half-year of EoQS"!

Comment: @AlexanderGruber Yea, the final effect on PSQs does sound hard to measure. But I think (e.g.) Paramanand's suggestion of counting flags from some months can reveal good. Do you agree/disagree? There might be other good ideas

Comment: @TheoBendit I can guess only 1 name, maybe 2. But one thing that really pushed me into asking for statistics is that I never really internalized the sheer scale of the site. [As of right now,](https://math.stackexchange.com/users?page=30&tab=reputation&filter=all) there are **thirty pages** of users over 10K rep. That's a thousand-ish people!

Comment: @AlexanderGruber A presumably naive, but hopefully workable future suggestion not necessarily for evaluation at present : if you're counting the number of PSQs, then why don't you ask people to flag PSQs (in addition to other actions that they will do anyway) with the flag text "This is a PSQ" or something like that? Then you can count ,at the end of the day, which questions were flagged with this text, and get a better idea of the PSQ situation. Of course, you will have to trust the community stance on PSQs and probably have to check the flags, that's why I called it naive.

Comment: @CalvinKhor It's not a bad idea, but one problem with counting flags is that number of flags is subject to both long term increase (proportional to growth of the userbase) and, probably more importantly, seasonal variation, which is very strong on this site (can't get into too many details cause of nda but something like 30% reduction when school's out). Both would be difficult to control for, and furthermore it would be difficult to interpret because its unknown how much of the volume difference would be due to bad questions (however one chooses to define "bad"). That ratio probably changes

Comment: seasonally as well. It's also hard to say whether more flags or closes are indicative of improving question quality, or increased community regulation, both of which are obvious theses one could have about EoQS. I think this is one of these situations where measuring indirectly is actually very difficult, and my hope is that somebody-- perhaps SE, perhaps a user group here-- can come up with a model that gives a rough direct measurement of PSQ volume.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Yeah crowd sourcing it might be the best solution we have. I think it would (vastly) overwhelm the flag queue, but maybe we could set up a separate site with a batch upload of question numbers? It's hard to say how useful it would be though, since again I think we'd need a lot of historical data to properly contextualize it. If we had a very dedicated group of users willing to go through many many posts, we could, say, select N random questions since 2015, then have everyone label them PSQ or not PSQ, and see if we have an idea of the trend. But N may need to be high.

Comment: @Jyrki You seem to be overlooking a crucial point. Most users are not aware that suspension length may escalate *exponentially*, e.g. that after a 1 month suspension the next may be for 1 year. With such knowledge they might have been much more careful before answering questions that are on the borderline of being PSQs or dupes (which may be a very subjective judgement on border cases). I think that it is only fair that mods warn users about such exponential escalation, but I don't believe that has ever been often done (now or in the past).

Comment: Further, I don't believe it is fair for the EoQS slaps-on-the-wrist / wakeup suspensions (or any analogous suspensions on *contentious* policies) to be lumped into the general escalation counts that are used for far more serious non-contentious issues (like cheating by voting rings, etc).

Comment: @AlexanderGruber I see. Thank you very much for pointing out that I'm a little naive re data! I'm still thinking about this...

Comment: @AlexanderGruber : I think we should not expect the change in PSQ numbers so soon. EoQS does not directly penalize PSQ askers and it will take a while to change the perception that mathse is not a PSQ answering machine. Rather we need to focus on the data as to how much percentage of PSQs are being answered before getting closed.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber: also the seasonal variation can be controlled comparing same months this year to same months last year (when there was no EoQS). But what I gather from all this is that we need a lot more discussion in order to understand how to measure the effects of EoQS.

Comment: @TheoBendit If you are so convinced that EoQS is bad, why are you not running in this election, rallying for support? In the previous election there was one candidate openly critical about most forms of quality control. They did not make it into top three IIRC. May be the voters are actually in favor of quality control measures, and your opinion is less popular than you think? Only one way to find out!

Comment: @paramand yeah-- we should take a look at some of the data together in a couple weeks, assuming you win.

Comment: You actually didn't get anything wrong, @Teresa.  It's just a couple of users do all they can to make you believe you misunderstood.  That's because of the use of rhetoric, rather than sound, valid arguments.

Comment: @Jyrki I'm not sure if you're trying to encourage me to run, or trying to talk me out of my views with an ad populum. I do not express my opinions because they are or are not popular, and my reasons for not running are my own business. One reason I'm comfortable sharing is that I don't believe that I would fit well into the moderation team such as it is. Perhaps, Jyrki, you might want to observe the popularity of your own position outside the CRUDE/meta echo chamber, and observe how people are actually using the site?

Comment: @TheoBendit  "and observe how people are actually using the site" what has this to do with anything? If anything it seems backwards.

Comment: @quid The message was mostly in response to Jyrki, interrogating the popularity of my opinions. I believe that the opinions on meta are not as representative of the community as a whole as we take them to be, and this seemed to be a core assumption in Jyrki's line of reasoning. But, I'm pretty sure this isn't what you wanted to discuss, so more to follow...

Comment: More generally (and controversially), I'm increasingly concerned that much of our moderation system is entirely at odds with how almost everyone uses our site. The site's ultimate purpose has to be the dissemination of mathematical knowledge (and hopefully skills too); a repository of Q&As that is unread and inaccessible is wasted effort. Not only does it take specialised skills and third party tools in order to search this site, but this is just not how our users tend to use the site. We're supposed to be for students of all levels, but we seem mostly suited to postgraduate level and above.

Comment: I take the role of moderators (diamond or no) quite literally: they are here to moderate the community. This means, let the community largely do its thing, and aim to curb self-destructive patterns. I am worried that we have spilled over from "moderation", and now we are in "control" territory. We are trying to mould the community into an ideal. I buy that, if the community conformed to this ideal (we all used MathJax, searched long and hard for existing answers, etc), then there would be no problem, but if the community doesn't conform, then we are proceeding from a false assumption.

Comment: I get that SE was created with a particular vision, and that it's reasonable to extend this vision to MSE, but the SE network is a different beast today than it was when it was founded. We now have sites like Code Golf SE, which are not really supposed to be comprehensive, searchable repositories of knowledge, and the SE network has adapted accordingly. I think we could stand to do a little adapting ourselves, to reflect how our site is used in practice.

Comment: Believe it or not, but I *generally* support us encouraging users to conform to our quality standards, both askers and answerers. They're not my weapon of choice, but down-votes are a sensible tool here. What I oppose is the enforcement through things like bans. When we start punishing people en masse for the sharing of good mathematical knowledge, this is where our community becomes self-destructive. This is where we need a little moderation in our moderation.

Comment: So, to address your second sentence more directly, I think it's both forwards and backwards. Not only should moderators have a hand in shaping the community, the community should be shaping the moderators too, and I don't just mean through elections. I think I'm finished now. :)

Comment: @TheoBendit Believe me, I am concerned about the opinions of users other than CURED regulars. My goal is to seek for a compromise that users will actually abide by. May be you didn't intend it that way, but you sound a bit like wanting to surrender the site to the homework solvers' club? That is not an optimal way of *dispensing mathematical knowledge*, do you think? "Popular" as it might be among A) lazy students, and B) people wanting to show that they can still do Calculus 101.

Comment: Group A could not care less about the site as long as Group B keeps spoon feeding them. The fact that Group B refuses to even discuss the matter is the most aggravating part. That is why I wanted you to run. May be "the people" would then come out and talk? [My past concern, see item 4](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27229/11619).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen The only thing I've called for here is the reversal of EoQS, not QS in general. I don't doubt that I sound like that to people; this has been the party line here for some time. CURED is very much like a political lobby group here: a group of people who have amassed great power, with unduly large sway over those in charge, as well as a tendency to put out "talking points" to keep the discourse on a track favourable to them. This is exactly the portrait they paint of those who defy them (answerers and askers). If you look at my comments, there's little to support this in my case.

Comment: I've always respected your sincere desire for dialogue, @JyrkiLahtonen. I hope we can achieve it too. But, I would recommend against propagating this mistrust in the users of MSE, because I suspect it blocks open dialogue, rather than helps facilitate it.

Comment: @TheoBendit A problem is that the olive branch business is not exactly thriving here. To the extent my views are cemented they are that way because I've been talking to a wall for a number of years. I do realize that their unwillingness to discuss comes from A) [Joonas's analogy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27238/11619) and B) the realization that to learn how the other side sees the issues takes quite a bit of effort. Like going through a few dozen past meta threads.

Comment: (cont'd) So a new user (in terms of meta experience) coming to meta, raising a point, is greeted with a link farm's worth of past discussions. Or a rehash of selected past arguments. This leaves every party dissatisfied, I'm sure :-(

Comment: How do "real" societies deal with problems like this? Making social studies education compulsory? The alternative, as Joel Spolsky put it, is to let matter run their course, leaving seventh graders take care of themselves. Lord of the Flies.

Comment: Sorry about not being clear about the following. What looks like *putting out talking points* is often about *we went through this in 2013*. I don't know how to resolve this.

Comment: @Jyrki I'm aware that this issue has massive legacy. I think I found, once, the proposal to ban PSQs. I remember there being a comment with eighty-something upvotes saying something like, "How about we ban proposals that ban questions with valid mathematical content?". I don't think there was a time when this compromise wasn't controversial, but you'd know better than me. That, to me, suggests not that the compromise should be made immutable, but that it should be discussed, and adjusted as our community changes over time. Spolsky's comment speaks mountains of disrespect for his user base.

Comment: All I'm really asking for is to revert to pre-EoQS. We can revisit 2020, not 2013. How the QS are enforced by the community is part of the compromise. I don't think the "homework mill" is the problem that you worry it is (in 2020, not in 2012), nor do I think the flood of duplicates rates as a "big" problem, when you weigh it against the fundamental problem of getting users without Latex skills to be able to search this site. I can't defend the position of those in 2013, especially not tonight. I am out of mental energy, so I'll have to sign off here.

Comment: @Theo "but down-votes are a sensible tool here" no they often are not because they have too little impact and (thus) little to no effect. There are users that get hundreds of downvotes and over all this feedback does not change their conduct at all. There are users that ostentatiously act counter to the QS, some even explicitly so. This is unacceptable and ought to have actual consequences. Otherwise we better drop the QS.

Comment: "I believe that the opinions on meta are not as representative of the community as a whole as we take them to be, and this seemed to be a core assumption in Jyrki's line of reasoning." Actually Jyrki was referring to elections not meta. Now, not everybody participates in elections either, but still participation is rather high, relative to other events.

Comment: "Not only does it take specialised skills and third party tools in order to search this site, but this is just not how our users tend to use the site." Actually most users use it exactly like this. Most users do not contribute actively at all. This phenomenon is very pronounced on SO but it also exists here. They may not even know the site specifically they just come across the information. I assume most of them prefer clearly and neatly presented information, as opposed to ambiguous posts that get clarified  (if that) in some comment.  Etc.

Comment: In any case that it is how I try to use the site. I need some clarification of some fact, and I search for it. Then I sometimes find something useful, but not rarely what I find is not so great. That's worse than on some other sites in the network, e.g., tex.se. Moreover there are a  few specific of my answers that get a relevant trickle of votes over the years which I am pretty sure is due to somebody actually finding the information. Your view seems to be shaped by the idea that we should mostly cater to marginally involved but visible users. @Theo

Comment: @Theo Sorry to come back to this. There is one thing I don't understand about your position. You have said that A) the way the rule was enforced was (or at least was seen to be) a part of the compromise, and B) you approve of QS without EoQS. I have a hard time trying to make sense out of this, asking myself the questions: 1) Where do you think the compromise is when one side makes no concessions? 2) Why do you think that a rule that is not to be enforced is a rule at all?

Comment: (cont'd) The best explanation I could come up with was that may the affected users think that getting their answers deleted is the enforcement and all the punishment. However, that explanation does not wash, because it will, for obvious reason, do nothing about the flood of PSQs. Which is what QS is all about.

Comment: sure we can have a 2021: year of EOQS, but it do last for only 1.5 months long... (not that i know anything about EOQS)

Comment: @TheoBendit It seems that [your concerns in this comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34283/can-we-have-2021-a-year-of-eoqs?cb=1#comment158837_34283https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34283/can-we-have-2021-a-year-of-eoqs?cb=1#comment158837_34283) are a litany of reasons to *support* EoQS.  Chiefly, EoQS is at odds with low quality questions and those who unwisely answer them, because such posts obscure the accessibility and searchability of good content.

Comment: @TheoBendit "The only thing I've called for here is the reversal of EoQS, not QS in general."  To paraphrase, isn't this just "I'm all for laws, just not enforcing them"?  In my experience that is the position people take when they want to retain the option to break laws when they feel like it, not having any real position from which to argue the law should be changed.  If one opposes EoQS, it seems they must be opposed to some standard being enforced.

Comment: @rschwieb Of those troubled by EoQS, most are uncomfortable with the E. It's gone from a point where nothing is happening, to a point where too much is happening. I think the stats on EoQS, and a little more transparency, might reveal the extent to which the QS were being violated, justifying the E : I must admit that I was surprised when suspensions were actually imposed, but rather than question them, I take them as signs that people weren't willing to listen to warnings or avoided interaction. But this is all stats-dependent : we need the stats to make a case in either direction.

Comment: @rschwieb By transparency, I'm referring to the trust that the mods discussed a middle ground(such as a talking-to or a warning) with QS-violating users before going into suspension territory. If this is true, then the number of suspensions doesn't reflect to me any sort of "control" : it just shows the level to which the QS was being violated that a large number of users were excessively stubborn about violating QS. The only point is, the lack of transparency (and a general break of trust) means that people can see this both ways. That's how it is with the conversation here.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Yes, that seems reasonable.  At the first order it would be good to know if, year over year, how the number of warnings and suspensions changes (someone mentioned this above of course.) I'd guess/hope there would be a rapid drop followed by slow inflation due to site growth.) Then at the second order is the harder-to-gauge effect of whether or not the flow of bad quality content slackens in the absence of encouragement of answers breaching the EoQS.  The first one seems like a quickly realizable metric but the second one seems more long term.

Comment: @TheoBendit It might have made sense for you to run.  Last time the campaign I referred to generated a lot of discussion in the election chat room, and we need more of that. Strictly your call, of course, and water under the bridge now.

Comment: It has now been one year since EoQS was first posted.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer: When users stubbornly continue to answer pure PSQs even after getting warned (and some even after the related suspension), we can only conclude that enforcement is **too lax**. However, as I have said before, we should be given some data: (1) How many users heeded warnings; (2) How many users refused to heed warnings, and hence were suspended; (3) How many users were suspended more than once for repeatedly violating the policy; ...

Comment: @user21820 Over the past few weeks the enforcement has slacked and the result is clear when one sees the close queue. I spent some time not reviewing, taking a back seat and observing site dynamics with a keener eye. This was after some disagreements with some other users, but the stance I took then was being too reliant on statistics. Rather than that (and following what I observed), what's visible is that the close queue is burgeoning and that violations shot up. I will do my bit with enforcement when I can.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer: Ok I see. I honestly can't tell what's happening or not happening with respect to EOQS. All I know is what I said above, and we clearly agree that regardless of what's happening it would be good to have more data.

Comment: @user21820 Definitely, we agree on that, and also agree on the enforcement being lax and having consequences lately. I take some responsibility here, and will step up as the weeks go on.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer: Sure, see you around! =)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Rather late, but there is no three strike rule for EoQS. I was banned for quite a while without warning and without explanation. I know one other moderately prolific contributor (50k+ rep like me) in real life. She also got banned for some months without warning and without explanation. We were both (at our own pace) first pissed off, then slightly afraid of answering and getting surprise-banned again, and then concluded that this forum is not worth the stress and frustration it gives us. Browsing here a few months later, it seems we were far from the only ones. Quite sad.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer A bit late, but see my comment above. There are at least two cases of no warning, no discussion, no explanation, just an immediate ban of some weeks or months. Unfortunately I am not aware of any general statistics. But returning here after a few months, it seems many other prolific contributors have been bullied away like this.

Comment: Somewhat ironically, it seems at a glance that the quality of the questions has dropped significantly. They may be mathjaxed and include some 'attempt', but they are almost all PSQ's and duplicates, but not treated as such anymore.

Answer (score 12):

There needs to be an analysis of whether this year's EQOS changes have improved the site or damaged it, and to what extent.  If a large part of the community identified a problem and felt something should be done, have the changes been successful or is this more an example of *this is something, so we must do this*?

1. The key question is whether fewer bad questions and more good questions are being asked. My impression is that the truly awful questions (such "see photo link" and nothing more) are still coming in at the same rate.
2. Are valuable answers to interesting questions being closed or deleted, when they would have survived before?  A recent example is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4302507/distribution-of-fracx-i-x-j-sum-s-1n-x-s2-x-i-sim-n0-1-independ) which has been closed, re-opened and closed again following a campaign in the CURED chatroom, with seven upvotes and seven downvotes and three sophisticated answers.
3. Does the new approach encourage types of questions which would previously been closed? A typical example would be questions of the "I know my detailed approach gives a wrong answer because I know the right answer, but why?" type  which previously closed as a duplicate of an earlier question showing a solution that works, but now survives because it is the opposite style to no-context questions that are now seen as particularly egregious.
4. Has the sense of community and mutual trust been damaged?  One group of intensive users feel that a substantial number of other long-standing users are deliberately ignoring the new approach.  Some of these other individuals feel they are being targeted by organised vigilantes determined to get them suspended from the site.

My view is that the answer to 4 is clearly yes, there has been damage and mutual trust is lower than it was a year ago.  That might possibly be worthwhile in an *ends justify the means* sense if the answers to 1, 2 and 3 showed that the site had become better as a result as a repository of useful questions and answers. And that is why the analysis needs to be done.

Comment: As I commented under the question, closure/deletion are not really related to EoQS. The question you linked in 2. is a PSQ and will be closed even before EoQS.

Comment: As a frequent close-voter I completely agree with 1. But again, it seems to me that EoQS is not directly related to that (though it seems that the ultimate goal is to decrease low quality questions). 4. is also true....

Comment: @ArcticChar I doubt it would have been closed a second time after it had good answers.  It may not have been closed at all: one of my old low-effort/high-vote answers looks like a response to [something which now looks similar to a  "problem statement question"  with 78 upvotes and 0 downvotes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/517555/fastest-way-to-check-if-xy-yx)

Comment: It's not 2013 now. That PSQ is discouraged was discussed [back in 13/14](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9201/proposal-discourage-questions-that-are-nothing-besides-a-problem-statement?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: I appreciate you raising your concerns. A big part of the problem has always been that the users getting targeted by EoQS flags and suspensions never seem to have read the related meta discussion. Further comments. About your point 1. It took several years for the site to develop a reputation as a do-my-homework mill. Putting a few answerers on a shorter leash is not going to magically erase that reputation in any short period of time.

Comment: 2. I cannot comment on the particular question for lack of familiarity with the topic. At a glance it looks like a totally unmotivated query with the potential to be a masked homework assignment. There is probably more to it, and we probably need to discuss further how to improve the appearance of such questions, and to what extent questions can be judged by their appearance alone. That will not be easy.

Comment: 3. Sounds like you are discussing about solution verifications and such. Yes, those are problematic. I think that discussion is currently going on elsewhere. It has even made to the list of the questions that the nominees in the current election are asked to address. I think that an even wider discussion is called for.

Comment: 4. I mostly disagree with this sentiment. The policy against PSQs cannot really be called *the new approach* given that the problem was identified ages ago, and the policies were discussed extensively, leading to a compromise rule on PSQs (that, by design, makes everybody unhappy). Any mutual trust was also erased a long time ago by the block of users who chose to deliberately ignore the rule while the other block was glenching their fists in disgust. Making the homework answering machines *accountable* is necessary for the lost trust to be rebuilt.

Comment: So from that point of view, mutual trust is now *improving*, because the other block can no longer ignore the rules. My fists have been relaxing a bit, and I have stopped casting EoQS downvotes (which was one of the rules/recommendations listed in the post where the moderators described the EoQS-policy).

Comment: Anyway, to me EoQS is chiefly targeting exactly the high-rep PSQ mass-answerers. Others most likely want to see a wider scope. Which is intellectually honest when the goal is to get rid of the homework-mill reputation.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: thanks a lot for your responses. I really never understood why most of the users who faced the EoQS sanctions never participated in meta discussions and elaborated their opinions.

Comment: @Henry What do you think about [Joonas Ilmavirta's analogy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27238/11619)? I suspect many affected users might share the feeling. That's fine, I suppose. But [in a comment under a follow up](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/32316/11619) I tried to explain how that attitude has lead to this schism.

Comment: Interesting questions/answers can always survive, one can always use their own context and their own attempts to write a new question, or use the context rewrite guidelines, or engage in context addition with OP. I wrote an answer on this [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34190/what-to-do-if-i-like-the-question-in-a-post-but-the-post-is-presented-in-a-bad-q/34192#34192) so the question in point number 2 should not survive (as someone with a background in probability)  but should instead have been taken up as an improvement project.

Comment: I agree with the last two sentences though. Point number 1 makes sense : although I would say the more important thing is , how those questions are dealt with after they come in (versus whether they come in or not, because the popularity of the site means that I cannot foresee their number reducing : the number of people who are going to come to this site not knowing what it's about is not going to change). Point number 2, response above. Point number 3 : Under discussion, but IMO people will want to close these questions. 4 : Disagree ref. Jyrki. Thank you for this post, though.

Comment: "I've counted at least 6 suspensions of high-rep users [...] all of whom have only ever output quality work, and endeavoured to help the users here as much as possible."  To get a suspension, they would have to be squandering their gifts on low quality posts.  Is there some shortage of good questions to answer that I've not yet heard about?  It looks to me like there are plenty such questions to go around.    Wouldn't it be better if they were spending their time on posts that clear the quality bar?

Comment: Why do bad posts deserve a great answer before their quality is rectified? Sometimes it doesn't take much at all to help make a bad question acceptable, and if the user learns how to ask a better question, another victory has been achieved.  Then there's no problem with an answer being contributed. Why is so much value being placed on the capability to answer a bad question before it has a chance to improve?

Answer (score 7):

I'm not involved in the site much anymore and don't know much about CRUDE or EoQS. I do know that the very low signal-to-noise ratio (with most questions being of the form "do this homework problem for me," and most effort going to answering these questions while more specialized, research-level questions get Tumbleweeds) is the main reason I stopped being as active here.

If certain users (a) saw that there was a *very* clear community consensus to stop writing "sophisticated" answers to low-quality questions; (b) decided, for whatever reason, to thumb their nose at this consensus; (c) stubbornly persisted despite multiple warnings from moderators; and finally (d) got banned, then in my opinion, good riddance. Whether these users were high-rep "[vested contributors](http://meatballwiki.org/wiki/VestedContributor)" or not.

Comment: $(a)$ has has never been true - and likely never will be w/o banning everyone whose viewpoint differs from $(a)$. So we've always strived for compromises - with varying degrees of success.

Comment: +1 It is irrelevant whether there is a consensus or not. The banned users ignore the *compromise* carefully designed to leave everybody unhappy. For me the nail in the coffin is the duplication. We have users who think that acing a Calculus 101  exam a hundred times (or some other exam at that level) makes them a hundred times more valuable as contributors.

Comment: I know that the EoQS  sanctions have also hit users capable of producing math well above what is typically seen in PSQs. What I cannot understand, why they want to keep their posting volume at higher level? When gifted with the ability to answer more difficult questions, skip the banal ones, please.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen even difficult questions can be PSQs too. so not a good idea to answer a qn just because it is difficult.

Comment: @cineel True. But that is unrelated to my gripe of capable users spewing out tons of banalities. A question can be banal even if it is not a PSQ. I would let competent newbies answer the simple questions for otherwise it is difficult for them collect rep points. As a veteran I step in only if the earlier answerers make a muck of it.